# Building a fridge in the wild

Tags: gear, survival, diy, improvised-gear, conservation

I've read that one can create a (actually a pretty decent) fridge with quite common materials a few years ago.

How do you do that?

Comment: @Aravona It was more something with digging a hole and aluminium foil... :)

Comment: Have you seen this [Which will keep my food colder longer, draining the melted ice water, or leaving it in the cooler?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/492/which-will-keep-my-food-colder-longer-draining-the-melted-ice-water-or-leaving)

Comment: Related - http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64716/how-does-an-earthen-pot-keep-water-cool#